# c# httpwebrequest 19th call fails

Tags: c#, multithreading, iis, httpwebrequest, webrequest

Odd behavior.  At least for what I've seen.  Need some guidance.  Here's my calling sequence:

```
httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strURL.ToString());
                httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
                strStatus = "Wait:GetResponse:" + pThreadName;
                mUpdateServerListCallBack(pServerID, pServerName, pServerInstance, strStatus);
                using (WebResponse webResponse = httpWebRequest.GetResponse())
                {
                    strStatus = "Wait:GetResponseStream:" + pThreadName; ;
                    mUpdateServerListCallBack(pServerID, pServerName, pServerInstance, strStatus);
                    using (Stream webStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream() ?? Stream.Null)
                    {
                        using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webStream))
                        {
                            string strResponse = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
                            responseReader.Close();

                            // Get ID list from response.
                            Int32 intIndexOfProcessingids = -1;
                            intIndexOfProcessingids = strResponse.IndexOf("Processing");
                            if (intIndexOfProcessingids > -1)
                            {
                                strReturn = strResponse.Substring(intIndexOfProcessingids + 15).Replace(". \"]", string.Empty);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                strReturn = string.Empty;
                            }
                        }
                        webResponse.Close();
                    }
                    httpWebRequest = null;
                    strStatus = "WebRequest:Closed:" + pThreadName;
                    mUpdateServerListCallBack(pServerID, pServerName, pServerInstance, strStatus);
                }
```

Calling Restful APIs on multiple servers - Trying to control it from a single server - a server marshall if you will.

I've got 5 API calls running across 5 different servers.  So, combination of Server 1, API 1, Server 1, API 2 ... through ... Server 5, API 4, Server 5, API 5.

I'm running each API call within a single thread, 4 threads at a time (Was trying not to overwhelm the server I'm running this on.)  So it runs 4 threads/4 APIS, then once one finishes, another one begins.  Basically 4 worker threads running at a time.  Again, each thread processing one API.

My problem is, I can't get this to run for more than 18 different APIs.  (Again, my test bed is 5 servers, 5 APIs each).  Always fails on the 19th Server/API combination.  Servers are all configured the same.  I can order the servers differently, doesn't matter.  I can run this with a single worker thread, in any order, 19 different times, and it ALWAYS fails on the 19th. I'm looping this, so once one thread finishes, it kicks off again.  But never works for the server/API combos > 18.  Never.

Tried the same thing with tasks, instead of manually controlling the threads - same difference.  18 tasks work.  Something about the 19th time.  Always fails.

When I say it fails, it's timing out on the Rest API.  I get a 500 error - my SQL Server is timing out from calls within the Rest API.

Any thoughts?  Any limitations on http requests from a single machine?  No idea where to go from here.

Thanks.

m

Comment: .NET Framework or .NET Core? Which OS? You cannot post a question without that essential information.

Comment: In ASP.NET framework, the default value of maxWorkerThreads is 20, but it also depends on number of CPU. One CPU can run one thread. But usually, ASP.NET won't let you use all threads run application, but keep one or two idle threads.

Comment: Lex - My bad.  First post, ever.  Bruce - Thanks for the insight.